# Google custom search how to set number of returned results

Tags: google-custom-search

I am using google custom search API for searching a site and trying returning the maximum possible results by setting the `num` param to some high number `999` but this is sending error to me :

```
(400) Invalid Value
```

But when i set `num` value to `10` or lower it works perfectly, So it seems like google is putting some limit on returned results.

[Here is my Google CSE link you can check by setting the num param](https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=WTB%20rolex&cx=015869402587641212464%3A2h4a9qay8rw&num=20&key=AIzaSyCSRSo1RTB3WB5uyZmFMUj0JajHWfWftTs)

Google CSE API docs are here : [API Docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list)

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 2):

you can retrieve max 10 page with max 10 results.
in query you can use 'num' and 'start' params to lead your request.

num = 1-10 how many results to show
start = 1-100 the starting point

So, if you need max results, you must to do 10 request with num = 10 (default) and start = 1, 11, 21, ... 91

Comment: I can't understand the downvotes, but I can confirm my answer.


Examples (your cx and key required):

`curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=super+goofy&cx=0...8&alt=json&key=A...k&start=1&num=11'`
doesn't work because you can't ask more than 10 results at time.


`curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=super+goofy&cx=0...8&alt=json&key=A...k&start=100&num=2'`
doesn't work because G not give more than 100 results.


`curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=super+goofy&cx=0...8&alt=json&key=A...k&start=1&num=10'`
this works :)

Answer (score -1):

```
"queries": {
  "nextPage": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - WTB rolex",
    "totalResults": "3030",
    "searchTerms": "WTB rolex",
    "count": 10,
    "startIndex": 11,
```

I think they want you to page through the result set. So, in this query, there are 3030 results and we're on page 1.

You can use the following parameters to specify which page you want:

```
"start": integer
```

It works, although I'm getting random 400s from it too (anything over 100 400s for me).

Comment: My best guess would be that these are account limitations of the free account. Does it change if you pay for the service?

Comment: :( Page through the results..  that is i want to avoid or want to lower the loop iterations and i dont have a paid account.